# WebSphere Liberty not finding log4j.properties in the classes dir of the WAR

Tags: java, properties, log4j, websphere-liberty

If I move the file outside of WEB-INF/classes into a directory loaded manually via:

```
<library id="global">
    <folder dir="C:\Temp" />
</library>
```

then all is good.  From everything I am reading, storing the properties file inside of the WAR WEB-INF/classes directory should be good enough, but it isn't working.

Here are the details of the WLP:

```
product = WebSphere Application Server 20.0.0.4 (wlp-1.0.39.cl200420200401-1714)
wlp.install.dir = C:/IBM/WASv9_Liberty/
java.home = C:\Temp\OpenJDK\jdk-10+44_windows-x64_bin_ri.tar\jdk-10+44_windows-x64_bin_ri\jdk-10
java.version = 10
java.runtime = OpenJDK Runtime Environment (10+44)
os = Windows 10 (10.0; amd64) (en_US)
process = 1948@DEV-WIN10-221
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

[EDIT]By not working, I am seeing a few things:

```
[err] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
[err] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[err] log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

None of my appenders are loaded and the logging level is not being loaded.

When I copy the properties file out of the classes directory and into the C:\Temp directory, the log4j:WARN messages disappear from the logs and the appenders/logging levels start working again.

Comment: And the log4j JAR is where.. WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: @Scott Kurz - Yes the WAR file is 100% self contained so the log4j JAR is in WEB-INF\lib of the WAR.

Comment: By "not working" you're seeing some kind of error, or it's just not logging with the expected behavior based on the config values you specified?

Comment: @Scott Kurz - Edited the question to give more details about what is not working.

Comment: It does work, we use it that way all the time. So... is your log4j jar in `WEB-INF/lib`? Any other log-related jars there, like Commons Logging or slf4j? Which features are enabled in your Liberty server.xml?

Comment: @dbreaux - I know it works since I have been using it for years myself.  It just stopped working very recently.  I am using SLF4J and the product supports JUL, Log4J, Log4J2 and Logback.  The Log4J build has slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar and log4j-1.2.17.jar.  The same build works on Tomcat (which means that Tomcat finds the log4j.properties file).  The Liberty instance where the testing happens only has jsp-2.3, adminCenter-1.0 and websocket-1.1.  It is as though I hit a limitation in Liberty (classpath size) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you are using MAVEN for building your WAR file?

For MAVEN build, the log4j properties file has to be placed under **src/main/resources** folder unless explicitly configured via java system property -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/path/to/log4j2.xml